# Using Java configuration for n-factor authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

In a Spring MVC app using Spring Security, I want to use a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to check **n-number** of additional fields beyond the default `username` and `password`.  For example, if a user wants to authenticate, I want her to have to supplement her username and password with a pin code she receives via email, a pincode she receives via text, and `n` number of other credentials.  However, to keep this question narrow, let's just focus on adding one additional pin to the login, but let's set it up in a way that enables us to add n-other credentials easily afterwards.

I want to use Java configuration.

I have created a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, a custom `AuthenticationFilter`, custom `UserDetailsService`, and a few other changes.

But the app is granting access when a user tries to log in whether or not the user has valid credentials, as shown in a screen shot in the instructions for reproducing the problem below.  What specific changes need to be made to the code that I am sharing so that the custom n-factor authentication can function properly?

The structure of my test project is shown in the following screen shots:

Here is the Java code structure in eclipse project explorer:

{ Image host not available }

The XML config files can be located by scrolling down in project explorer to show the following:

{ Image host not available }

The view code can be found by scrolling a little further down in project explorer as follows:

{ Image host not available }

You can download and explore all this code in a working Eclipse project:

{ File now deleted }

`CustomAuthenticationProvider.java` is:

```
package my.app.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));  
        } 
        if(pincodeEntered(name)){
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("registered"));  
        }
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    private boolean pincodeEntered(String userName){
        // do your check here
        return true;
    }
}
```

`MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java` is:

```
package my.app.config;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Order(2)
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

`TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.java` is:

```
package my.app.config;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{
    private String extraParameter = "extra";
    private String delimiter = ":";


    /**
     * Given an {@link HttpServletRequest}, this method extracts the username and the extra input
     * values and returns a combined username string of those values separated by the delimiter
     * string.
     *
     * @param request The {@link HttpServletRequest} containing the HTTP request variables from
     *   which the username client domain values can be extracted
     */
    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request){
        String username = request.getParameter(getUsernameParameter());
        String extraInput = request.getParameter(getExtraParameter());
        String combinedUsername = username + getDelimiter() + extraInput;
        System.out.println("Combined username = " + combinedUsername);
        return combinedUsername;
    }

    /**
     * @return The parameter name which will be used to obtain the extra input from the login request
     */
    public String getExtraParameter(){
        return this.extraParameter;
    }

    /**
     * @param extraParameter The parameter name which will be used to obtain the extra input from the login request
     */
    public void setExtraParameter(String extraParameter){
        this.extraParameter = extraParameter;
    }

    /**
     * @return The delimiter string used to separate the username and extra input values in the
     * string returned by <code>obtainUsername()</code>
     */
    public String getDelimiter(){
        return this.delimiter;
    }

    /**
     * @param delimiter The delimiter string used to separate the username and extra input values in the
     * string returned by <code>obtainUsername()</code>
     */
    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter){
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig.java` is:

```
package my.app.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
            CustomAuthenticationProvider impl = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
            return impl ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/secure-home")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure-home").hasAuthority("registered")
                .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .and()
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
}
```

`User.java` is:

```
package my.app.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name= "email", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String login;//must be a valid email address

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "pin")
    private String pin;

    @Column(name = "sessionid")
    private String sessionId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id;}

    public String getPhone(){return phone;}
    public void setPhone(String pn){phone = pn;}

    public String getPin(){return pin;}
    public void setPin(String pi){pin = pi;}

    public String getSessionId(){return sessionId;}
    public void setSessionId(String sd){sessionId = sd;}

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    //roles methods
    public void addRole(Role alg) {roles.add(alg);}
    public Set<Role> getRoles(){
        if(this.roles==null){this.roles = new HashSet<Role>();}
        return this.roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> alg){this.roles = alg;}
    public boolean isInRoles(int aid){
        ArrayList<Role> mylgs = new ArrayList<Role>();
        mylgs.addAll(this.roles);
        for(int a=0;a<mylgs.size();a++){if(mylgs.get(a).getId()==aid){return true;}}
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The xml config is in `business-config.xml` and is:

```
<beans profile="default,spring-data-jpa">
    <!-- lots of other stuff -->
    <bean class="my.app.config.SecurityConfig"></bean>
</beans>  

<!-- lots of unrelated stuff -->
```

In addition, `mvc-core-config.xml` contains the following:

```
<!-- lots of other stuff -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />
```

And `login.jsp` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Custom Login page</title>
    <style>.error {color: red;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Custom Login page</h1>
        <p>
        <c:if test="${error == true}">
            <b class="error">Invalid login or password or pin.</b>
        </c:if>
        </p>
        <form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" >
        <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Login:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"size="30" maxlength="40"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" size="30" maxlength="32" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pin:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="pin" id="pin"size="30" maxlength="40"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </form> 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The spring security dependencies in 'pom.xml' are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Download and reproduce on your machine

I have also uploaded a working Eclipse project which contains the bare minimum code required to reproduce the problem on your local devbox. You can download the Eclipse project here:

{ File now deleted }

Once you have downloaded the zipped project, you can reproduce the problem on your machine by following these steps:

1.) Unzip the zip file to a new folder

2.) In Eclipse, do `File > Import > Existing Maven Projects`

3.) Click `Next`. Browse to folder of unzipped project.  Complete wizard to import project.

4.) Right click on project name in eclipse and do `Maven > Download sources`

5.) Right click on project name again in eclipse and do `Maven > Update project`

6.) Open MySQL and create an empty new database called `somedb`

7.) In the Eclipse project, open `data-access.properties` as shown in the following picture, and change `someusername` and `somepassword` to your real username and password for your MySQL.

{ Image host not available }

8.) In Eclipse, right click the project and chose `Run As .. Run on server..` .  This should launch the app so that you see the following in your browser at the `http://localhost:8080/n_factor_auth/` url:

{ Image host not available }

9.) Change the URL to `http://localhost:8080/n_factor_auth/secure-home` to see that you were redirected to `http://localhost:8080/n_factor_auth/login` which serves the sample custom login page, which requires a pin in addition to the username and password.  Note that the result needs to accommodate `n-factors` and not simply adding a single pin code:

{ Image host not available }

10.) Insert test credentials into the MySQL database by running the following SQL commands, which you could put in a `.sql` file and run from the MySQL command line using the `source` command.  Note that the database objects will be deleted and recreated empty every time the app starts because `hbm2ddl` is enabled to simplify this example.  Thus, the following SQL commands will need to be re-run every time you reload the app in Eclipse.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT INTO `roles` VALUES (100,'registered');
INSERT INTO `user_roles` VALUES (100,100);
INSERT INTO `users` (id, email,password, phone, pin) VALUES (100,'me@mydomain.com','somepassword','xxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyy');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

11.) Try to login using **any** credentials (valid or invalid), and get the following successful login screen (Note that the user gets logged in whether or not they give valid credentials):

{ Image host not available }

That's it.  You now have the problem recreated on your machine, including all the code shown above, but in a working minimalist eclipse project.  So now how do you answer the OP above?  What changes do you make to the code above, and what else do you do in order to get the custom authenticator to engage upon login?

I am interested to learn what specific changes need to be made to the minimalist download app in order to enable n-factor authentication.  I will validate by checking your suggestions in the sample app on my machine.

Thanks to various people (including M.Deinum) who have suggested deleting redundant XML config to create the current version shown in this posting.

Comment: @Inject is part of import javax.inject.Inject; so if you get type error its because the jar is not part of your project.You need to edit your main pom.xml/file with dependency to add it or download the jar and add it to the build path.You took userService from the other example tread but it can be anything just so you know.

Comment: you add the depency given by maven repository, you put this within the <dependencies> tag in pom.xml.                                                          <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: can i know why you are using hibernate over here? I think its not needed

Comment: have u connected with ur db. which db r u using?? if connected means then no need to change.if there is a need such that if some thing can be done inside Spring JdbcTemplate means i will let you know.

Comment: ok..i will have a look into it

Comment: if username+password is working. then adding pincode should also work as per my code..

Comment: 2 step authentication is easy and possible too..

Comment: Why are you mixing xml and java configuration for security? The xml stuff is breaking everything... The `/**` permits access to everyone, basically rendering your further configuration useless. Next to that your java configuraiotn isn't doing anything with the additional configuration stuff (the filter isn't registered). So not sure what you are trying to do but due to the complexity you introduced yourself (combining xml and java configuration) it doesn't work. Choose either xml or java don't try to mix them.

Comment: The access denied is due to the fact your roles don't match, when the user logs in you give him the role `ROLE_PINCODE_USER`. However your security requires a role `registered` those don't match hence a 403.

Comment: Because that is how you have written your `AuthenticationProvider`. You are always returning an `Authentication` object. You aren't checking anything or throwing exceptions. So everyone will get the role `registered`.

Comment: I don't know either because that is the code YOU need to write. YOU know the specs we don't. Also you should be throwing an exception imho when the username/password doesn't match. To  me it looks like you are trying to put 3 tutorials together without knowing how the framework actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to use java config for n-factor authentication is to start with a working example of single-factor authentication (username and password) that uses java config.  Then you only have to make a few very minor changes:  Assuming that you have a working single factor authentication app using java configuration, the steps are simply:

First, define layered roles, with one role for each factor.  If you only have two factor authentication, keep your existing one role in the database, but then create a second role with full-access that you only assign at runtime.  Thus, when the user logs in, they are logged in to the minimal role stored in the database, and that minimal role is only given access to one view, which is a form allowing them to enter a pin code that your controller just sent them via text or email or some other method.  These layered roles get defined in `SecurityConfig.java`, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/getpin")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/getpin").hasAuthority("get_pin")
            .antMatchers("/securemain/**").hasAuthority("full_access")
            .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
            .and()
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Second, add code that upgrades the user's role to full-access upon successful entry of the correct pin code to the controller code that handles the pin code entry form `POST`.  The code to manually assign full access in the controller is:

```
Role rl2 = new Role();rl2.setRole("full-access");//Don't save this one because we will manually assign it on login.
Set<Role> rls = new HashSet<Role>();
rls.add(rl2);
CustomUserDetailsService user = new CustomUserDetailsService(appService);
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities(rls));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
return "redirect:/securemain";
```

You can add as many layers as you want to after `/getpin`.  You can also support multiple authorization roles and make it as complicated as you want to.  But this answer gives the simplest way to get it running with java config.

Answer (score 7):

First, some explanation about the interfaces you are working with and the role they play in the authentication process:

- [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) - represents the result of authenticating a user. Holds the authorities granted to that user and any additional details that may be needed about the user. As there is no way for the framework to know, what details are going to be needed, the authentication object has a [`getDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails%28%29) method that can return any object
- [`AuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) - object that can create an `Authentication` object in some way. To make them more reusable, some (or most) of `AuthenticationProvider`s refrain from setting the user details on the `Authentication` object, as each application may need specific user details. Instead they delegate the process of resolving the user details to a settable `UserDetailsService`
- [`UserDetailsService`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) - a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for retrieving the user details required in your application.

So, if you are creating a custom `AuthenticationProvider` you may not even need to implement it in a way that requires a `UserDetailsService`. The decission is up to you and depends, on whether you plan on reusing your implementation in other projects.

As for the compilation problems in your code, you are mixing two ways of providing the `UserDetailsService`. In the `CustomAuthenticationProvider` you have annotated the `userService` field with the `@Inject` annotation .This means, that the container (Spring application context in your case) is to find a suitable implementation and inject it into that field at runtime using reflection. The process of setting this field by the context is called dependency injection. In the `SecurityConfig` class you are trying to provide the implementation yourself by setting the field through the `setUserDetailsService` method that does not exist in your class.

To resolve this problem you need to decide to use one of the ways to provide the UserDetails service and either:

- remove the `@Inject` annotation and create the `setUserDetailsService` method, or
- remove the line when you are calling the non-existant method and declare your implementation of the `UserDetailsService` as a bean

As for which of the ways should you choose, the dependecy injection way may by better if you can find a way of making your `SecurityConfig` class reusable in other projects. In that case you could just import it (by using the `@Import` annotaion) and declare a different `UserDetailsSerice` implementation as a bean in your next application and have it working.

Usually, classes like the `SecurityConfig` are not really reusable, so creating the setter and removing the dependency injection would probably be my first choice.

**EDIT**

A working, albeit a simplistic implementation (based heavily on this [blog entry](https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/)) would be:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));  
        } 
        if(pincodeEntered(name)){
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PINCODE_USER"));  
        }
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    private boolean pincodeEntered(String userName){
        // do your check here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your config class change the following method:

```
@Bean
AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The first thing we need to do is extend the [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) class so that it can handle a second input field.

```
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{
    private String extraParameter = "extra";
    private String delimiter = ":";
    //getters and setters

    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String username = request.getParameter(getUsernameParameter());
        String extraInput = request.getParameter(getExtraParameter());
        String combinedUsername = username + getDelimiter() + extraInput;
        return combinedUsername;
    }

}
```

**obtainUsername()** This method is to retrieve the username and “extra” input field from the HttpServletRequest object that’s passed in.

It then concatenates these two values into one string, separating them by the delimiter string (a colon, by default).

It then returns this combined string. The parameter from which the “extra” input field is read is extra by default.

**UserDetailsService** should look like this:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String input) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
{
    String[] split = input.split(":");
    if(split.length < 2)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Must specify both username and corporate domain");
    }

    String username = split[0];
    String domain = split[1];
    User user = userDao.findByUsernameAndDomain(username, domain);
    if(user == null)
    {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or corporate domain");
    }
    return user;
}
```

Split the given username into its two components: the username and the extra field. In this example, the extra field is the user’s corporate domain.

Once we have the username and the domain, we can use our DAO to find the matching user.

Last Puzzle:

**TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter:**

```
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/secured" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.awnry.springexample.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" class="com.awnry.springexample.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/processLogin" />
        <beans:property name="postOnly" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="extraParameter" value="domain" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?login_error=true" />
    </beans:bean>
```

In twoFactorAuthenticationFilter bean definition, we set the extraParameter property to “domain” which is the name of the input field to use in our login form.

EDIT:

Have a look into constructors of [User](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) class.

If you don't know what a granted authority get into a look over this below link:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html

Your coding gives a different mode applicable only for normal username and password. My code works for n factor authentication. Try switch over to my code if any problem keep on persists.

Answer (score 4):

I'm very concious that this post has undergone 28 edits, so I may have missed some context. I'm also concious that you've amalgamated some code from the other answers into your question and that the problem has been somewhat "turned on its head" from "why won't a valid user authenticate?" to "why does every user authenticate?".

#### Current problem.

However, as written, your `CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` method will always return an `Authentication` object that returns `auth.isAuthenticated() == true` because you instantiate using [this method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html#UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection%29) which warns you about that very thing.  Even if the `collection` you passed in as the third argument were empty, this would be the case.  In fact, the collection always contains a `GrantedAuthority` for "registered", because `pincodeEntered(name)` always returns `true`.  So, you need to correct your logic in those methods.  `authenticate()` should return `null` if authentication is not successful.

#### Next steps

You've [indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020405/using-java-configuration-for-n-factor-authentication?answertab=active#comment52590659_32020405) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020405/using-java-configuration-for-n-factor-authentication?answertab=active#comment52591572_32348464) that what you want is a reference implementation of multi factor authentication.  This is problematic - there is not necessarily agreement on what would constitute such a thing.  For instance some would argue that multi factor should include a possession factor, rather than n knowledge factors on a single login page.  It's also not really suited to an SO answer as it would need a blog post (or a series) - however generous the bounty.

There are working examples of multi factor authentication in spring on the web, [here](http://www.gobloomhealth.com/multi-factor-authentication-part-1/) and [here](http://blog.awnry.com/post/16183749439/two-factor-authentication-and-spring-security-3), for example.  The latter I think you must have discovered as you appear to be using some of the code from there.

Making your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` work might take hours. Debugging might take even longer, as you have a mixture of methods in your example - it is not minimal.  In particular, the `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter` class is supposed to be used to intercept input on a request from the login page and concatenate the username and pin.  In the example from the blog, this is [set up in XML](http://blog.awnry.com/post/16183749439/two-factor-authentication-and-spring-security-3) - you could add the `security` namespace to your `business-config.xml` and add those beans there for instance.

However, the `SecurityConfig` class and `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is a different method again.

Next, your project code references a `j_security_check` url, but that URL is not handled by anything.  I am not sure of the intent behind that, or where it comes from.  Finally, the MVC config for URL routing adds another element to the mix - one which I'm not familiar with.

I've played with your example for a while. There are too many mixed methods and too much complexity for me to fix quickly - maybe others can.

I ***strongly*** suggest that you start from the example in the blog exactly, then add the mvc config you want to over the top of that.

#### N.B. Setup for others trying to get the example to work

There were a couple of wrinkles in setting the project - it had an un-needed and unsatisfied dependency on `javax.mail`, you need to publish the maven dependencies to the server (in project->properties->deployment assembly) and you need to download and install adapters for the tomcat server if you don't already have it.

You also need to create the tables and columns in your database.

Comment: @CodeMed Any changes inside the logic will reflect the configuration files also

Comment: @MSIbrahim I think I might remove this answer to be honest.  The question requires too many changes to my setup and I'm not sure I can participate with the wording OP has put to try to specify conditions on an answer. Maybe you can work on the above to make your answer satisfactory for OP.

Comment: I set up all that (took a while - didn't have a working install of tomcat or anything), but Tomcat errors when running the project from eclipse, saying it can't find a class in one of the spring jars. `ContextLoaderListener`.  I haven't got time to debug it, I'm afraid.  If I get chance later, I'll see if I can update some further ideas.

Comment: Hmm - curiosity bit - I managed to get that working.  A web search makes me think you're trying to [adapt this blog post](http://blog.awnry.com/post/16183749439/two-factor-authentication-and-spring-security-3) - is that right?  If so - it's usually easier to put that up front in the question, so people know they're working on someone else's code that works in a different context.

Comment: I can replicate both your initial problem (old zip) and the current one (new zip). I think there is too much to resolve on SO here. For instance, your `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter` is not referenced anywhere in the project - i.e. it's not being used in authentication. Similarly `CustomUserDetailsService` is never used at all. The `CustomAuthenticaionProvider` doesn't work for the reason in the answer above. There are other (non-code) security issues - you shouldn't be storing raw passwords and pins in your database - they should be hashed.

Comment: @CodeMed I am worried that you are trying to shoehorn Stack Overflow into a role it can't meet. I don't require bounty.  rep is pretend internet points that cannot buy my time in any real sense. I help where I can and I'm interested, but it requires questioners to play by the rules - in particular to ask concise questions about specific issues. Not to ask for project work in return for rep. Sure, it's a nice gesture to offer bounty and I often take a look at bounty questions. But the other rules still apply.  There is no onus on answerers to answer in a particular way etc.

Comment: That being said - I've had a look at your project.  Here's one further link - using [spring-security with spring-mvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html).  If you can get a minimal project going with one of the links I've provided (truly minimal, not mixing the different types of security mechanisms) and have specific questions, then sure - I'll take a look.

Comment: Sure, so it goes. That's an issue with the model here - sometimes its hard to tell what works. But it is the model. We've interacted before on bouncycastle/pgp I recall. You can be sure, I've downloaded your project, got it running and replicated your problems (took some hours, but I found it intriguing, my choice). I'm telling you that it's not minimal and has (at least) two different security mechanisms mixed up in it. I cannot understand **specifically** what you can't replicate from a **single one** of the web examples (not mix of all) / why you can't extend your current single factor app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88840/discussion-between-j-richard-snape-and-codemed).

Comment: Do you know AngularJS?  I have a related question about setting up Spring Security as a REST service used by an AngularJS app.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406376/hooking-up-mysql-user-data-to-angularjs-spring-security

Comment: @JRichardSnape I think my problem was that I needed to create a dataSource bean for MySQL and inject it into SecurityConfiguration.java.  I got an example to work with Thymeleaf today.  Tomorrow I will try to replace Thymeleaf with AngularJS to solve the problem in my preceding link.  But for now I got the github code in the following link to work, and I decomposed it into its elements.  Spring security is a little different when there are separate apps running on client and server:  http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/30/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/

Comment: @JRichardSnape In case you are interested, I resolved my new question.  I am sending you this because I get the sense you have an intellectual interest in the topic, but that you are just swamped with grad school.  Here is how I found the solution to the new problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443843/how-do-i-merge-these-two-spring-boot-controllers/34443971

Comment: @CodeMed Thanks - very interesting, but yes - study and christmas limiting my ability to digest :) Will read through when I can.  All the best!