# How do I merge these two Spring Boot controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

**How do I merge the two controllers below with different annotations into one controller?**  I am trying to set up a Spring Boot app that uses AngularJS on the front end with MySQL-based Spring Security authentication on the back end.

Towards this end, I have been studying [the code in this example which links AngularJS with Spring Boot Security and authentication from server-side config](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular) and from [this other example, which uses MySQL-based authentication to a Spring Boot backend of an app that uses Thymeleaf as the front end.](https://github.com/jrodenbostel/beyond-the-examples/tree/master/part-5)  Both example apps are up and running in my devbox, but now I need to merge the back ends of both apps so that the `/user` url pattern is available for backend authentication by the front-end app, while also causing authentication to be done using the `dataSource` bean from the MySQL backend example.

The problem is that the controller in one app uses `@SpringBootApplication` and `@Controller` annotations, while the controller in the other app uses `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations.  **How do I reconcile these annotations so that one controller can contain code that is currently segregated across both apps?**

Here are the annotations for the controller in the first app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class UiApplication {
    //lots of code
}
```

And here are the annotations for the controller in the second app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //lots of code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` is actually a meta annotation, which consists of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`. So you can just make your `UiApplication` extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and copy all code from Application to UiApplication (of course check if you then have duplicate beans and fix that appropriately).